# Create instance from base class and maintain typings

Tags: typescript

I have a problem trying to get the base class to infer the types of the parent class

```
abstract class Record {

    //...

    static findRecord(id: number){
        // this creates will create an instance of the prototype "this"
        // prototype of "this" will equal Node later
        return new (Object.getPrototypeOf(this))(id)
    }
}

class Node extends Record {
  statements(): Array<Statement> {
     // ...
  }
}

let node = Node.findRecord(1)
// type is "any" (as findRecord doesn't infer the type as "Node", because Object.getPrototypeOf(this)) can equal anything)

node.statements() // This has no typings in vscode
```

I would like typescript to know that the type of the Record will be the class that instantiates it (in this case Node)

I need the type of the instantiated `node` to be `Node` so that the typings for `.statements()` are available, and I would like to avoid duplicating code and having to put it in each class that extends from `Record`.

Comment: Apparently, this is a very common problem in typescript [https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Based on @Titian's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899566/typescript-inheritance-using-static-method), you need to make your `findRecord` method into a generic function where `T` describes the specific class instance.  You use a `this` argument as an ignored first argument so that typescript can infer the type of `T` based on the value of `this` when you call it.

```
abstract class MyRecord {

    constructor(id: number) {
    }

    static findRecord<T>(this: new (id: number) => T, id: number): T {
        return new this(id);
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/oN978W)

### An Alternative Approach

Personally I have bought into the "inheritance is bad" mantra so I would move shared `static` logic into a separate class which can be instantiated for each record type by passing that record's class as an argument to the constructor.

```
class RecordFinder<T extends BaseRecord> {

    private readonly recordClass: RecordConstructor<T>;

    constructor( recordClass: RecordConstructor<T> ) {
        this.recordClass = recordClass;
    }

    find(id: number): T {
        return new this.recordClass(id);
    }
}

interface BaseRecord {
    id: number;
}

type RecordConstructor<T extends BaseRecord> = new (id: number) => T;
```

Here I am restricting the type of `recordClass` based on an interface, so it doesn't matter whether `MyNode` extends `MyRecord` or not.

```
const nodeFinder = new RecordFinder(MyNode);

const node = nodeFinder.find(1);
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/DmMPQN)