# TypeScript - Access sub class type from base class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to construct a base class that would be inherited by some sub classes. Inside the base class, I'd like to add multiple static creator functions that'd be easy to use in the codebase. The problem is, I can't access the type of the sub class from the base class.

For example, this is the base class:

```
class BaseClass {
  static fromText(text: string) {
    const element = getByText(text);
    return new this(element);
  }
  
  static fromRole(role: string) {
    const element = getByRole(role);
    return new this(element);
  }
}
```

And this is the sub class:

```
class SubClass extends BaseClass {
  doSomething() {
    console.log('doing something');
  }
}
```

Now, I want to call `doSomething` from `SubClass`. The problem is, TypeScript doesn't know this function exist inside `SubClass`:

```
const subclass = SubClass.fromText('hello');
subclass.doSomething(); // TypeScript error here, saying doSomething doesn't exist
```

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think this is direct duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899566/typescript-inheritance-using-static-method. That little trick with the generic in the static method lets `this` be child constructors. See https://tsplay.dev/Nn4JoW for a working example in in your code.